# as3 merge variables and event listeners

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, puzzle, event-listener

I'm kinda new here so don't be angry if I do something wrong. I am working on a little puzzle game and I'm running into a "issue". I have these pieces which all has their own variable.

And im trying to make a function that allow me to drag and drop these bad boys. Although because they all are seperate variable i have to make lots and lots of event listeners and drag and drop functions. So my question is how do I merge these variable and event listeners so I only have to make 1 function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I get your point here, but please post some code, because we can only imagine how sparse your variables are, plus we could help you with your context thus making it easier for you too :)

Comment: You could put all of the puzzle pieces into an array/vector, then iterate over the array and put the same event listener for each piece.  Anyway, aduch is right.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth: could you put a single listener on the stage, then upon touchdown/clickdown test if there is one of the bad boys right below your touch/click event, and then proceed to your drag'n drop until released ?